# Disambiguation/rename of [swift] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Apple just announced their new programming language, [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/) ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/LandingPage/index.html)).

The [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) tag is currently used for [the OpenStack Swift object store](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/), but this only has 56 questions. It should probably be renamed to [openstack-swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openstack-swift), or something. (Perhaps someone who actually uses it can suggest a better tag.)

I expect Swift to quickly become an extremely high-traffic tag on Stack Overflow. Therefore it seems more convenient to just use the tag [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) for the language, rather than something more specific [apple-swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-swift) or [swift-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-language). (Apparently there is also [an existing language named Swift](http://swift-lang.org/main/), but I don't think there are any questions about it, so it's not a concern.)

Any disagreement?

Comment: Easy solution.  Just use NSSwift as the new language tag.

Comment: This keynote was streamed live online, and I watched from home. No NDAs here.

Comment: the book "The Swift Programming Language" is available in iBooks, AFAIK without restriction.

Comment: [NDAs: Not our problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94465/should-moderators-enforce-ndas-for-software-vendors) This comes up every year at this time.

Comment: Which takes precedence for a tag? Temporal primacy or popularity? It's a tough question in my mind.

Comment: It seems [swift language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-language) has been created for this but whether or not that's a great name, IDK.

Comment: *makes note to check for existence of SO tag before picking names for things*

Comment: _Swift Language_? Is that like _agile programming_?

Comment: just swift-lang,sounds good.

Comment: Whether you like it or not, the more popular one is likely to win the most straight-forward tag.

Comment: `swift-lang` is no good because it would probably cause confusion with this: http://swift-lang.org (Apple even link to this on the Swift homepage). I think people are going to use `swift` even if it remains as the Open Stack Swift tag, so it may be easier to just change it.

Comment: What makes you think anyone is actually going to use this new language anyway?

Comment: @AShelly: Are you kidding? The fact that it is the primary programming language for a very large mobile platform makes it inevitable.

Comment: @Chuck: Why yes, yes I am.

Comment: @AShelly: …I knew that. Totally.

Comment: I notice questions about Apple's Swift language are now tagged both  both [apple-swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-swift) and [swift-language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-language).

Comment: I've moved the old [tag:swift] questions over to [tag:openstack-swift]. You guys can argue amongst yourselves whether you want [tag:apple-swift] or [tag:swift-language] (currently the one being used), but a) don't edit the tags back and forth, b) we're not going to use just plain [tag:swift] for either one, and c) **no edit warring back and forth between tags**. Talk it out. Go.

Comment: If swift isn't going to be used for either should it be added to a blacklist? I know that's normally only done in extreme cases, but I'd imagine a lot of people would create a new swift tag for the language if they don't see one already

Comment: Also it seems like someone has completely burninated apple-swift.

Comment: @connor I merged [tag:apple-swift] because the rollbacks between tags were causing the stats to be off and at the time there weren't any questions with it anyways.

Comment: @animuson Since you didn't choose to "talk it out" yourself, I must ask why you have decreed that we won't just use `swift`. It will surely dwarf any other usage of the term by a factor of hundreds or thousands. `go` is theoretically a potentially ambiguous term, and the name of a previously-existing language, but nobody is suggesting we should be using the tag `go-language` instead. `windows` is potentially ambiguous with the standard GUI element, but we don't insist on the tag `windows-operating-system`.

Comment: I've never found it a good idea to use ambiguous tags just because one technology dominates over the others. If we can prevent the ambiguity from the get-go, we should take the opportunity being provided to us. A synonym to whichever tag is chosen seems like a better option. That would at least emphasize which Swift technology the main tag refers to.

Comment: Let's make it simpler: leave [tag:swift] alone, and prohibit all questions about everything of, by, or related to Apple. :-)

Comment: Why is Swift now a synonym of Swift-Language instead of OpenStack-Swift? Wouldn't it be more logical to set it as a synonym of the tag it used to relate to for 5 years prior to Apple coming along?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Synonyms don't serve any purpose for past questions, only future questions. There have been more questions asked about swift-language in the past day than there have ever been about openstack-swift, so I think it's fair to say that this synonym will help more users than the alternative.

Comment: I have nothing to do with mobile development, but... um... wow. Steamrollered much?

Comment: @Ben: [And not for the first time.](http://www.cultofmac.com/143006/how-steve-jobs-steamrolled-cisco-on-the-name-iphone/)

Comment: If you search the tag list for "language" you see that swift is the only programming language in the whole of stack overflow with the suffix. Since Swift is intended to replace the 9th most popular language in the world, it absolutely deserves a proper tag. SO should be consistent, the tag should be [swift].

Comment: ... ObjectiveC.NET.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: I frequently get contacted by recruiters looking for iPhone app developers because my resume says I have Cisco IOS experience, correct capitalization and full context, with neither Apple nor iPhone appearing anywhere.  Annoys me greatly.

Comment: @animuson [tag:swift] is a thing!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### Outcome

- The tag for Apple's new language is [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift).
- The tag for OpenStack's object store has been renamed to [openstack-swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openstack-swift).

Comment: A poll is being conducted to gauge community opinion on this outcome: [\[swift\] or \[swift-language\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259995/tag-name-poll-swift-or-swift-language)

Comment: After strongly winning the poll, `swift` will be the name of the tag going forward.

Answer (score 32):

The programming language is called Swift so we should use that tag for Apple's new programming language. The current version of Swift (parallel scripting) has not been updated since 2011, so I don't expect a lot of people to use it.

I see that at at [this page](http://swift-lang.org/main/index.php) the name Swift/T is used. So I suggest to use either [swift-t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-t) or [swift-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-lang) for the old Swift language and [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) for the new Swift language.

Comment: Swift/T is a particular implementation of the older Swift language, not a synonym for the whole language.

Comment: i think [tag:swift] needs burned to reduce confusion.

Comment: `swift` has more name collisions than *just* the old language, there are also other things called "swift" that aren't languages.  We need complete disambiguation here.

Comment: [tag:swift] is burned.

Comment: `swift` got revived 47 minutes ago.

Comment: ...in the sense of the tag wiki being created/edited. No questions.

Comment: apple+swift = apple-s = apples?

Comment: @RohanBüchner the tags apple-s and apples don't tell anything about the swift language.

Comment: haha, yes of of course they don't. wrong place to try and show my humorous side I guess...tough crowd ;)

Answer (score 5):

I think the Apple one should be [apple-swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-swift) and the old one should be [swift-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-lang). OpenStack Swift should be [openstack-swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openstack-swift). The old [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) should be focused at [openstack-swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openstack-swift).

Comment: There are no questions about the "old one." It doesn't need a tag  and quite possibly never will.

Comment: @Chuck it would be good to at least document it even if gets used eventually.

Comment: I don't think we do pro-active tagging.

Comment: Can't do a tag without a question... and frankly, it's best left out here.  People don't read tag wiki excerpts, and `swift-lang` *will* get misued.  +1 for the unambiguous `apple-swift` tag.

Comment: That was quite a unilateral tagging you just did, Daniel.

Comment: @Charles `apple-swift` doesn't solve `swift` problem -- what I see currently is that although there is a `apache-spark` tag, people who ask about it (new distributed processing framework) keep marking their questions with a simple `spark`, [which is already occupied by (abandoned) Flex technology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark). **The same pattern will emerge for `swift`.**

Comment: @om-nom-nom, which is *exactly* why we need *complete* disambiguation.  `swift` should go away entirely.  `spark` should also go away.

Answer (score 1):

Well in my opinion something went wrong along this discussion. Right now there are 4 tags each more or less affilated with Apple's Swift language:

- [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift)
- [swift-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-lang)
- [swift-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-language)
- [swift-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-ios)

In my opinion: [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) (since shortest and most obvious) and [swift-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-language) are best and could stay. [swift-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-lang) and [swift-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-language) do not differ except that it would be shorter but a bit more cryptic.

When you write "swift-lan," you automatically get [swift-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-language) suggested, so in my opinion there is no need for [swift-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-lang)

[swift-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-ios) is useless in my opinion, since you can just multitag your question with [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift)/[swift-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-language) and [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios).

Comment: Plain "swift" is not sensible - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258076/disambiguation-rename-of-swift-tag#comment34514_258076

Comment: `swift-ios` is a really bad idea because Swift can and will be used to program on platforms other than iOS—OS X, for starters, and then others once compiler support arrives. If a question pertains to Swift *and* iOS it should be tagged with separate `swift` and `ios` tags.

Comment: I think the current setup is reasonable: the actual tag is `swift-language`, but `swift` is a synonym of it, so users who just type that will also get the result they expect. `swift-lang` is also a synonym.

Comment: @JeremyBanks But why so many synonyms? Even more if you search for a tag you won't normally start with language but with swift. Since you get auto suggestion it would be enough to have swift and maybe swift language. But another is just unneccessary in my point of view.

Comment: I just made [swift-ios] a synonym of [swift-language]. [I have a feeling I'm going to have to make a few more.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24052739/revisions)