# How do you tag a question about a programming language which has homonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

Sometimes a very popular programming language shares the same name of a more "obscure", specialized one. You would like to ask a question about the least popular one.

[E.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30726604/swift-versus-swift-parallel-scripting-language):

- **[Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/)** is a mobile programming language designed by Apple, recently open-sourced.
- **[Swift](http://swift-lang.org/)** (Parallel Scripting Language) is a totally different beast, predating Apple's Swift, and which is used to control the
  execution of parallel tasks on large systems, typically for scientific computing.

I just noticed that the authors of the latter have now started to call their language Swift-k, probably in despair.

Tagging a Swift Parallel Scripting Language question "**swift**" looks very confusing to me. 
Maybe even mentioning "**swift-k**" as a tag could be too confusing.

Do you just create a new tag "on the spot" in these cases?
Is there an accepted good way of creating new tags appropriately?

Would **swift-k** or rather **swift-parallel-scripting** be the correct choice?

How are these issues resolved?

i.e.: Is there "a right way" to tag this sort of niche and confusingly named programming languages questions ?

Incidentally speaking, searching for "**swift-k**" on SO results in totally unrelated questions, all about the more famous Swift programming language.

Comment: Wait, The parallel scripting language is not the same as [openstack-swift](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258076/disambiguation-rename-of-swift-tag)?

Comment: If apple is involved, they are resolved the [800 pound gorilla way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/800-pound_gorilla). Anyone else will get squished out of the way.

Comment: If the authors renamed it to swift-k then surely questioners are going to start using the [swift-k] tag.  Why is that a problem?

Comment: Openstack-swift? That's a "blob store". i.e.: not remotely connected with either of the two programming languages. Worse than expected, we have 3 opportunities for confusion.

Comment: [other-swift]?​

Comment: @TinyGiant: Since that was proposed for either the pre- or post-open-source Apple Swift tag, I somehow don't think that will help matters.

Comment: [not-apple-and-not-openstack-but-parallel-scripting-swift]

Comment: @NathanTuggy: It wasn't meant to.

Comment: Tagging question about Apple's Swift language was discussed in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258076/disambiguation-rename-of-swift-tag and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259995/tag-name-poll-swift-apple-swift-or-swift-language. Apparently, the community decided to re-tag all "Openstack Swift" questions.  I found only a single reference to the Swift Parallel Scripting Language in that discussion: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258110/1187415.

Comment: I don't know why everyone is focusing on the swift-k issue, it is given as an example of this kind of thing arising, not the problem the poster wants to resolve. He seems to want a rule as to how to handle similar issues in the further.

Comment: Funny side note: At the time of writing the question linked by @rene, there were 56 questions tagged "swift". As of now there are 67.895 questions. In not even 1 and a half years. Amazing.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I read that as a little less than 68 questions, not 68k. That gets confusing.