# Tag for Modular Mojo

Tags: discussion, tags

There seems to be no tag for [Modular Mojo](https://www.modular.com/mojo), a new programming language for AI developers.

I've added [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76230176/208273) on SO and tagged it as [modular-mojo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modular-mojo), to avoid conflict with [Maven's Mojo](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/index.html), Maven plain Old Java Object, which is tagged as mojo.

--- edit

The tag `modular-mojo` is now deleted from the question, in preference for `mojolang` tag.

Comment: You don't have to ask permission to create a new tag, typically...while yes, if the question or the tag are also bad there's a lot of clean-up that needs to happen, but in this case I think it's OK.  I *did* have to get rid of the PR-reading noise in the question though (like, who *cares* where Modular Mojo came from?  You want your question about Modular Mojo answered), so just keep that in mind.

Comment: The [mojo] tag may also need some disambiguation, from the excerpt it's possible to use it for multiple things. *SDK for development of webOS 1.x and 2.x apps using JavaScript and HTML. or... Most commonly used to designate plugin development in Maven (Java build tool).*

Comment: @Lino ugh, yeah, that's...not great.  That really should be two tags.

Comment: I dunno if it's worth it. Austin Powers 2 kinda ruined mojo for me.

Comment: @Makoto where do you read that I'm asking for permission? Everyone with tagging creation permission can create tag the way they want, you should know that. It's about consistency in tags... but then again, whatever, this language only has 2 questions in SO so who cares.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have an opinion on what the tag name should currently be, but FYI [mojolang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mojolang) was already created, so those should be made consistent in one direction or another.

Comment: @Makoto You're mistaken (edit: or not, maybe we miscommunicated). That's literally what Stack Overflow did for the last language created by Chris Lattner, creator of Mojo: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258076/disambiguation-rename-of-swift-tag Now, that is the _most extreme_ possible case -- nobody's suggesting this is going to be on the scale of Swift -- but I think most folks would agree it was the right move then, and it might be again if this language takes off. (As a nit: the existing mojo tag isn't a language, it's a framework for a platform that was dead almost on-arrival.)

Comment: @Makoto It seems like [tag:mojolang] and [tag:modular-mojo] *are* the same thing. [The only question in the mojolang tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76168724/208273) links to the Modular site.

Comment: @RyanM:  Oh, I misread this answer then.  Maybe I glommed too much onto the sensationalism part.

Comment: My general thought is that if there starts to be a lot of confusion between the existing [tag:mojo] tag and Modular Mojo, then we'd probably just rename the mojo tag to something like [maven-mojo] and...probably not create a synonym.  That way users are shown both and can easily pick the right one.

Comment: I've updated the tag in my question to `mojolang`. So as of now there's 2 questions tagged `mojolang` and none tagged `modular-mojo`.

Comment: +1 for renaming `mojo` to `maven-mojo`

Comment: (Not to be confused with "[Dojo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dojo_Toolkit)" (in our minds).)

Answer (score -2):

With the first sdk release of Modular Mojo today, there is an uptick in questions regarding it. The tag is currently a mix of Maven and modular mojo questions. It would be a good time to separate the two tags.

Comment: There already are two separate tags.