# Is overloading [mojo] bad mojo?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

There is the tag [mojo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mojo) with description "SDK for development of webOS 1.x and 2.x apps using JavaScript and HTML. or... Most commonly used to designate plugin development in Maven (Java build tool). For the Perl web toolkit, use [mojolicious](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mojolicious) Mojo is also a programming language and superset of Python. Check https://www.modular.com/mojo for more details"

As it suggests, this is also [being used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77070883/performance-comparison-mojo-vs-python) for the programming language [mojo](https://www.modular.com/mojo).

It looks like some disambiguation is needed.

Comment: Best options would probably be to have a `maven-mojo` and `mojo-lang` tag. Which one is newly created and which one is renamed from the original depends on the respective volume. Instead of a rename a synonym would probably also work. I.e. make `mojo` a synonym of `mojo-lang` after all the retagging has been done.

Comment: @Lino Who can do that?

Comment: @Lino In general, I'd oppose adding the synonym after such a split. Having such a synonym tends to result in people continuing to misuse the synonymed tag, due to not completing the selection of the tag they actually want.

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424658/tag-for-modular-mojo

Comment: Per the [top answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424659/14906662) of the linked question, the [tag:mojolang] tag already exists

Comment: As contributor to Maven, I can't see any reason why you'd want to use that tag in that context. It's too granular. [tag:maven-plugin] does the job perfectly fine.

Comment: In that case, it might be a good idea to add `[maven-mojo]` as a synonym to `[maven-plugin]`

Comment: Just saw a [new one today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77089348/mojo-error-an-error-occurred-in-python).

Comment: At the very least, could someone with tag wiki excerpt editing privileges remove that last line and add a note pointing people to the correct [tag:mojolang]? Currently the tag looks as if it was meant to be used for both Java/Maven-related and Python/Mojo-related questions.